# How to select all text in a JFormattedTextField when it gets focus?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I have a small Java desktop app that uses Swing. There is a data entry dialog with some input fields of different types (JTextField, JComboBox, JSpinner, JFormattedTextField). When I activate the JFormattedTextFields either by tabbing through the form or by clicking it with the mouse, I would like it to select all the text that it currently contains. That way, users could just start typing and overwrite the default values.

How can I do that? I did use a FocusListener/FocusAdapter that calls selectAll() on the JFormattedTextField, but it doesn't select anything, although the FocusAdapter's focusGained() method is called (see code sample below).

```
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField pricePerLiter;
// ...
pricePerLiter.setFormatterFactory(
    new JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory() {
    private NumberFormatter formatter = null;
    public JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter 
        getFormatter(JFormattedTextField jft) {
        if (formatter == null) {
            formatter = new NumberFormatter(new DecimalFormat("#0.000"));
            formatter.setValueClass(Double.class);
        }
        return formatter;
    }
});
// ...
pricePerLiter.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
    public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        pricePerLiter.selectAll();
    }
});
```

Any ideas? The funny thing is that selecting all of its text apparently is the default behavior for both JTextField and JSpinner, at least when tabbing through the form.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Wrap your call with SwingUtilities.invokeLater so it will happen after all pending AWT events have been processed :

```
pricePerLiter.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
    public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pricePerLiter.selectAll();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I can only guess that the NumberFormatter is doing something that undoes the selectAll()?

Comment: +1 Needed this, could not remember instantly how to do this my self, googled and immediately found this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to execute it with an invokeLater when you already are on the EDT thread?

Comment: Because `invokeLater` makes sure that all pending AWT events have been processed

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the above, if you want this for all text fields you can just do:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
    .addPropertyChangeListener("permanentFocusOwner", new PropertyChangeListener()
{
    public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getNewValue() instanceof JTextField)
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    JTextField textField = (JTextField)e.getNewValue();
                    textField.selectAll();
                }
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Thats because the JFormattedTextfield overrides processFocusEvent to format on focus gained/focus lost.

One sure shot way is to extend JFormattedTextField and override the processFocusEvent  method :

```
new JFormattedTextField("...") {  
        protected void processFocusEvent(FocusEvent e) {  
            super.processFocusEvent(e);  
            if (e.isTemporary())  
                return;  
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
                @Override  
                public void run() {  
                    selectAll();  
                }   
            });  
        }  
    };
```

Using a focusListener might not always work..since it would depend on the time at which  it is called relative to the processFocusEvent.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is kind of old, but I came up with a cleaner solution, without invokeLater:

```
private class SelectAllOfFocus extends FocusAdapter {

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        if (! e.isTemporary()) {
            JFormattedTextField textField = (JFormattedTextField)e.getComponent();
            // This is needed to put the text field in edited mode, so that its processFocusEvent doesn't
            // do anything. Otherwise, it calls setValue, and the selection is lost.
            textField.setText(textField.getText());
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't like this code, since it modify component internal state, just to get selection?

Answer (score 2):

The code of camickr can be slightly improved. When the focus passes from a JTextField to another kind of component (such a button), the last automatic selection does not get cleared.  It can be fixed this way:

```
    KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
        .addPropertyChangeListener("permanentFocusOwner", new PropertyChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent e)
        {

            if (e.getOldValue() instanceof JTextField)
            {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                    JTextField oldTextField = (JTextField)e.getOldValue();
                                    oldTextField.setSelectionStart(0);
                                    oldTextField.setSelectionEnd(0);
                            }
                    });

            }

            if (e.getNewValue() instanceof JTextField)
            {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                    {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                    JTextField textField = (JTextField)e.getNewValue();
                                    textField.selectAll();
                            }
                    });

            }
        }
    });
```