# How to select text in JTextField while tabbing

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JDialog` with a series of `JTextField`s on it I would like the text each to be selected when I tab to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This exact question has been asked and answered, check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178312/how-to-select-all-text-in-a-jformattedtextfield-when-it-gets-focus/1178596#1178596).

Short version: Add a focus listener to your text components and select all on focus, using SwingUtilities.invokeLater to ensure all pending AWT events have been processed.

Comment: I did do a search first but didn't find that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

Call `selectAll()` in the `focusGained()` of the [`FocusListener`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html)

Comment: Worked fine for me. I prefer it to the other answer.

Comment: It works if you don't have a formatter installed. My suggestion would be to move this code into a helper class that you use every time when you create a field (maybe a builder or maybe extend `JTextField`).